# Touchpad not working after a while

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, touchpad

I keep having trouble with my 12.04LTS install!

I now have everything working fine the way I want but the touchpad does not work anymore... It was not working at first during the install and the first boot. It started working after installing the Nvidia driver `331-update` and after reboot it stopped working again...

I would like to know if someone know a work around for this.

I already tried the :

`sudo modprobe -r psmouse
 sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps`

solution, and it is not working for me.

My computer is a Gigabyte P35K, with a Nvidia GTX 765M.

Answer (score 0):

ok, this might be stupid, but have you made sure you haven't accidentally hit the FN+ what ever Fkey turns off your touch pad?

try pressing it a few times and see what happens

Comment: Yes and it has not been effective